# Deferred_output for cyclical iteration in Python 2.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

[Here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576961-technique-for-cyclical-iteration/) I found a very good recipe of how to calculate a sequence of number using a technique with **deferred output**.

I decided to use the same technique to solve the second problem from [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/problems).

The code:

```
#Answer: 4613732
from itertools import *
import operator

seeds = [1,2]

def deferred_output():
    for i in output:
        yield i

result,a1,a2 = tee(deferred_output(),3)
paired = map(operator.add,a1,islice(a2,1,None))
output = chain(seeds,paired)

cropped = takewhile((4000000).__gt__,result)
evened = filter(lambda x: x%2==0,cropped)

print(sum(evened))
```

The code worked perfectly in Python 3.x

But when I tried to run it in Python 2.x the following error rose:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Oleg\Мои документы\_Мои документы\_SyncedWithFlashDrive\Программирование\Project Euler\2\1.py", line 14, in <module>
    paired = map(operator.add,a1,islice(a2,1,None))
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Oleg\Мои документы\_Мои документы\_SyncedWithFlashDrive\Программирование\Project Euler\2\1.py", line 9, in deferred_output
    for i in output:
NameError: global name 'output' is not defined
```

It means that **deferred output** doesn't work in Python 2.x

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following code works:

```
from itertools import *                                                         
import operator                                                                 

seeds = [1,2]                                                                   

def deffered_output():                                                          
    for i in output:                                                            
        yield i

result,a1,a2 = tee(deffered_output(),3)
paired = imap(operator.add,a1,islice(a2,1,None))   # change 2 (imap)
output = chain(seeds,paired)

cropped = takewhile(lambda x: x <= 4000000,result) # change 1 (lambda)
evened = filter(lambda x: x%2==0,cropped)

print(sum(evened))
```

and i needed to make two changes:

first, the argument to takewhile needs to be a lambda because integers in 2.7 don't have methods like `__gt__`.

second, and more importantly, `map()` in python 3 is lazy - it returns a generator that does the work later.  in contrast, in python 2.7, it is eager - it does the work straight away and returns a list.

so, in python 2.7, the `map()` triggers evaluation of the code, which calls back through the various generators until it evaluates the `deffered_output()` function.  and this all occurs *before* the line where `output` is defined.  so there is an error, because `output` is undefined.

however, in python 3 (or when using `imap()` in python 2.7) that line creates another generator, which doesn't actually do the work until things are evaluated in the `sum()` (and by that point, `output` is defined, so it's ok for `deffered_output` to be evaluated).

if that's not clear then you need to learn more about [generators](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) in python.

ps not important, but it's driving me crazy to look at it: it's "deferred", not "deffered"!

Comment: Thanks. How did you track it down? I thought it was connected with "outmost-iterable-precomputation" problem. So I thought the behaviour has changed in Python 3.x (though wasn't able to find enough information about it). So I didn't even think about `map<->imap` (though initially, when writing code I wrote `imap` because of a habit and changed it only to `map` when an exception popped).

Comment: Thanks for the other corrections! `__gt__` I used primarily because I was afraid that `lambda` would slow everything down.

Comment: About the spelling of `deferred`. Sorry for that. I was careful while writing the question (hope there are not misspelling of this word in it), but the code was just copied via clipboard. And that is where I was sloppy. I edited the post to correct all the misspellings.

Comment: well, first i spent a long time trying to work out how it could be related to a change in scoping, but i couldn't find anything in the python 3 release notes, and then i noticed that the stack trace comes from the `map()` when that code should not be evaluated until later.  and then finally i realised that someone pointed this out in the original page where you got the code from!  no worries about deferred :o)